# Is it possible to open ModelBuilder SCREEN from .NET base command class?

Tags: arcobjects, modelbuilder, arctoolbox

I simply want to open the custom model's SCREEN (ModelBuilder) from .NET.

Comment: Tags modified to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 5):

When your command is run inside ArcMap (should work in ArcCatalog and other applications as well):

```
        var arcToolBoxExtension = _app.FindExtensionByName("ESRI ArcToolbox") as IArcToolboxExtension;

        if (arcToolBoxExtension != null)
        {
            var arcToolBox = arcToolBoxExtension.ArcToolbox;
            var gpTool = arcToolBox.GetToolbyNameString("MyModelName");
            if (gpTool != null) arcToolBox.EditToolSource(gpTool);
        }
```

Where _app is an IApplication reference, and "MyModelName" is the Name of your model. Note that the Name is different from the model's Label - you can find both in the tool's properties on the General tab as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Thank you.  Thank you.  Works perfectly!  Just what I need.

Comment: Sorry for being a nitwit.  But, where do I click to mark this as answered? :)

Comment: I suggest you skim over FAQ http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq to get to know how the site works, it will help you understand asking/answering questions and other things, like reputation, which you will find useful.