# Opening a custom model's geoprocessor window with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, .net

I have developed a custom model using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS, and I would like to use a .NET Base Command to open the geoprocessor parameter window for this tool so the user can enter their parameters, same behavior as if I were double-clicking it in ArcToolbox, as opposed to just executing it programmatically without user interaction. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open ModelBuilder SCREEN from .NET base command class?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/is-it-possible-to-open-modelbuilder-screen-from-net-base-command-class)

Comment: @Petr This isn't a duplicate. The answer to the question you posted at the link opens up the model in the ModelBuilder editor window. I want to open the tool's geoprocessing tool dialog, the canned one that lets you enter parameters, view help on the right, and set environment at the bottom: [Tool Dialog Basics](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Tool_dialog_basics)

Comment: you're right, sorry, I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very similarly to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/is-it-possible-to-open-modelbuilder-screen-from-net-base-command-class/2235#2235), you can open a tool's dialog with the code below. The code sample opens up the dialog for the "Symmetrical Difference" tool, but you can use your model's name instead of "SymDiff".

```
        // _app is an IApplication reference (e.g. ArcMap or ArcCatalog app)
        var arcToolBoxExtension = _app.FindExtensionByName("ESRI ArcToolbox") as IArcToolboxExtension;

        if (arcToolBoxExtension != null)
        {
            var arcToolBox = arcToolBoxExtension.ArcToolbox;
            var gpTool = arcToolBox.GetToolbyNameString("SymDiff");
            if (gpTool != null) arcToolBox.InvokeTool(_app.hWnd, gpTool, null, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Petr has shown the answer, which is the GetToolbyName property on IArcToolbox.  You can also refer to the SDK manual which will help you navigate the SDK:

[IArcToolbox.GetToolByName](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/GetToolbyNameString_Method/002p0000001w000000/)