# Executing ModelBuilder using C# classes?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcobjects, modelbuilder, c#

How can I execute ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.1 using .NET 2013 C# classes?

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/is-it-possible-to-open-modelbuilder-screen-from-net-base-command-class?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
but I'm interested in executing Model builder without openning ArcMap if is it possible of course

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to execute an existing model that you have developed, not just the ModelBuilder software interface?

Comment: Yes exactly. I've already a custom developped model builder so i want just to run it using parameters without I open Arcmap through C# .NET 2013 .

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a recent example of this, or an example in C#, but you can [call any tool in your toolbox (including custom models) via ArcObjects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002p00000019000000).

This [older example in VBA](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27277) provides the basic structure for this process.

EDIT: This [more recent example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000) makes use of the modern geoprocessor to call a custom toolbox and execute a tool. There are VB and C# examples.

Comment: I would like to say that I'm working with 2013 and Arcgis 10.2.2 so as I heard from some friens that VS2013 isn't yet compatible with Arcgis 10.2.2 till 10.3 version so that I'm trying to make sure it this talk is really exist or not.

Comment: You could always use Visual C# 2010 Express, which is free from Microsoft.