# Trying to execute ModelBuilder through C#?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, modelbuilder, c#

I have a problem when trying to execute a model builder through C# the application throws:

> an error has occurred error hresult e_fail has been returned from a
>   call to a COM component

Note : ArcGIS 10.1 and .NET 2010

CODE :

```
 using System;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing;

namespace GeoprocessingInDotNet2008
{
    class Program
    {
        private static LicenseInitializer m_AOLicenseInitializer = new GeoprocessingInDotNet2008.LicenseInitializer();

    [STAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load the product code and version to the version manager
        ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);

        //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
        //m_AOLicenseInitializer.InitializeApplication(new esriLicenseProductCode[] { esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo },
        //new esriLicenseExtensionCode[] { });

        // Create geoprocessor. Overwrite true will replace existing output
        IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

        // Get the workspace from the user
        string wks = @"C:\Users\AmineMed\Documents\ArcGIS\LYDEC\DataBases";

        // set the workspace to the value user entered
        gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", wks + "\\" + "Temp.mdb");

        // Add the custom toolbox to geoprocessor
        gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\Users\AmineMed\Documents\ArcGIS\LYDEC\ConverterTool.tbx");

        // Create a variant - data are in the workspace
        IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
        parameters.Add(@"C:\Users\AmineMed\Desktop\mise à jour\El Mejjatya\Plan topo Al Wiam\Plan topo Al WiamT15071c.dwg");
        object sev = null;
        try
        {
            gp.Execute("Creation", parameters,null);
            Console.WriteLine(gp.GetMessages(ref sev));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            string errorMsgs = gp.GetMessages(ref sev);
            Console.WriteLine(errorMsgs);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine(); // pause the console to see messages
        }

        //ESRI License Initializer generated code.
        //Do not make any call to ArcObjects after ShutDownApplication()
        m_AOLicenseInitializer.ShutdownApplication();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: that's a very unhelpful error. Have a look at the exception object and see if you can get the e_fail code, that would help a bit, and while we're talking code how about putting a bit into your question to see if there's any obvious mistakes.

Comment: You'll need to **edit** the question to include your code before anyone could possibly help

Comment: This seems to be the fourth time that you have asked what is essentially the same question.  To conform to GIS SE protocols would you please be able to go back to the first of these and either **edit** or accept it, so that we can figure how to help you from there.  It is unclear whether you followed the advice there, and then become stuck at the next hurdle, or have gone off in a different direction.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149135/executing-modelbuilder-using-c-classes
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151403/how-to-execute-a-modelbuilder-through-c-arcobjects
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152062/connect-net-application-to-arcgis-model-builder
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152836/problem-while-trying-to-execute-a-model-builder-through-c

Comment: This has also been cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140743/cant-execute-a-model-builder-trought-c-sharp-net-2010-error-hresult-e-fail  Please do not cross post.

Comment: From your code on stack overflow what is gp.Execute("Creation", parameters,null);? "Creation" isn't the name of a tool, is that your model? Does that work from the toolbox? The exception or IGeoprocessor2 should have the value for the HRESULT which would be *very* helpful in trying to work out what's actually going wrong. The code does look fine so the problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Mr PolyGeo I didn't yet resolve the problem i'm still searching how to fix that error. I'm a bit confused because i've already installed all necessary softwares but still the same as you can see on the post.

Comment: Stick your GP.execute in a try catch and do a log/messagebox on GP.GetMessages(<severity>) to get the full error text

Comment: NEED HELP PLEASE !

Comment: I suspect that you would get more help if you refrained from using ALL CAPS to shout out that you need it as an alternative to the recommended procedure of continuously editing your question to make what you have tried and where you are stuck clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch to fetch error messages from the gp object.

```
    try
    {
        GP.Execute("Creation", parameters, null);
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        Messagebox.Show(GP.GetMessages(<severity>));
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code but the message exception still the same

Comment: @AmineMed Did you try all message severity levels? I usually find something in there. What tool are you trying to run by the way?

Comment: no I didn't. The tool I use is "DAO to Database" "Append" and "delete database" on one Model builder but I've already tried too just DAO to database but still no change.

Comment: NEED HELP PLEASE !

Comment: @AmineMed I suspect that you would get more help by editing your question to make what you have tried and where you are stuck clearer.